# Exporting passwords

Tags: gnome-keyring

So, I'm doing a backup of my home folder from ElementaryOS (based on Ubuntu 10.10 I think) and got to the point where I wanted to find and save the hidden folder for my passwords... wifi ones and the like.

Well as I couldn't find it I searched around and found the passwords / keys gui in system>preferences.

Everything I need seems to be in there but the option to export is greyed out!

Can I use this gui as sudo to overcome it? or is there something even more simple I'm missing?

If it makes any difference - I have an encrypted system (just the home folder I think)

Thanks for any help - it's the last step in my backup

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The application you are seeing is "[Seahorse](https://wiki.gnome.org/Apps/Seahorse)", which manages the [gnome keyring](https://wiki.gnome.org/Projects/GnomeKeyring). Its [distributor's website](https://wiki.gnome.org/Projects/GnomeKeyring/Distributors) tells us:

> > File Locations
> >     Gnome Keyring looks for passwords and encryption keys in the following locations: 
> >     `~/.gnome2/keyrings`: Password keyrings, keys and certificates.

The export option is only available for certificates, not for passwords.

To sum it up: Backup `~/.gnome2/keyrings`, and you have your passwords.

Answer (score 15):

In new versions of GNOME 3, the file is saved in `~/.local/keyrings` or `~/.local/share/keyrings`.

Answer (score 5):

As of the date of this post, I'm using GNOME 3.28.2, and this is located in `~/.local/share/keyrings`

Answer (score 1):

For Ubuntu `18.04`, Gnome: `3.28.3` the location for files is
`/usr/share/keyrings`